# How do I execute a method on an entity after it has been loaded in Spring Data Neo4j >=v6

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In Spring Data Neo4j 5 there was an annotation @PostLoad similar to other persistance frameworks. This annotation seems to be gone in version 6 (I'm using 6.1.6)

I want to populate some transient properties, after the node has been loaded.

Comment: There isn't such a functionality in SDN 6+. I wonder why you need this information in a `@PostLoad` method call. Wouldn't it be sufficient to calculate the transient values "on first access"?

Comment: @meistermeier That was my workaround solution, that has now become the permanent solution, I guess. It makes the code a bit bloaty, but it's feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gerrit's comment, there is no such function in SDN 6+.
The solution is to initialize your transient values in your getters.

Here is a very simplified version of what I did:

```
@Node
public class Event {

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String title;
    @Transient
    private Integer year;
    @Getter @Setter
    private ZonedDateTime fullDate;

}

public Integer getYear() {
    public Integer getYear() {
        if (year == null && this.fullDate != null) year = this.fullDate.getYear();
        return year;
    }
}
```

Semantically this code does probably not make sense, because the real code is much more complicated. So please don't comment things like "You would not need a transient attribute for this."